# Docker: "pg_restore input file does not appear to be a valid archive" error

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker

I backup a PostgreSql database using the following command and it creates an sql file:

```
cmd /c 'docker exec -t <container-name> pg_dump <db_name> -U postgres -c 
   -v > C:\\backup\\<db_name>.sql'
```

However, I cannot restore the sql backup file using the following command:

first I drop and create an empty db:

```
docker exec <container-name> bash -c "dropdb -U postgres <db_name>"
docker exec <container-name> bash -c "createdb -U postgres <db_name>"
```

then restore:

```
cmd /c "docker exec -i <container-name> pg_restore -C -U postgres -d 
  <db_name> -v < C:\\<db_name>.sql"
```

gives *"pg_restore: error: input file does not appear to be a valid archive*" error. So,

**1.** how can I restore the database with sql file?

**2.** how can I backup PostgreSql db in Docker on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

A plain-text `pg_dump` is restored with `psql`, not with `pg_restore`.

I don't understand why you want to run that inside the container. Install a PostgreSQL client on the host operating system and simplify the procedure. Besides, a backup should be on a different machine than the database.

Comment: Actually I have thought different approaches for Docker and PostgreSQL. Mounting data to a host drive instead WSL2 is not good for performance. The only thing I want to do is making things simple, but as I am new in Docker, I am confused a little bit. Could you please clarify me about the following issues?

Comment: **1.** Should I use WSL2 (Ubuntu) part for keeping all my Docker containers and volumes?

Comment: **2.** When using WSL2 part, how can I backup and restore database easily? Can I backup directly to Windows part and restore database using the backup file from Windows part?

Comment: 1) I have no idea. I don't use Windows. 2) Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Thanks for reply. For **#2**, could you post the backup and restore commands to your answer?

Comment: They are just like the ones you use, only without the `docker exec ...` in the beginning.

Comment: But the ones I used does not working and this is the problem.

Comment: Yes. I told you in my answer that you need `psql` to restore a plain format dump.

Comment: Sorry, but your answers are not a complete answer and spent my time. I hope you know what you suggest!